# asp classic 0x800a01a8 error

Tags: dll, asp-classic

I need to run a very old application that was build using asp classic. This application has a series of dlls that are supposed to be installed as com+ components.
One of the asp pages uses a function called register that is in a dll called TS. This dll is installed as a com+ component.
On the asp page I have this:

```
Set oControl = Server.CreateObject("TS.Control")
```

When trying to call the page I get this error:

```
0x800a01a8 - TS::register - TS: Object required
```

Control is the class module name.

Since the dll is installed as a com+ component, what else could cause this error? I am running this on a windows 7 with IIS 7.5

Comment: I found a post to suggest it may be an authentication issue. http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?558534-VBScript-runtime-%280x800A01A8%29-Object-required-Application%28-%29. I'll delete my incorrect answer.

Comment: The following link suggests adding the dll as a reference. http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1376600

Comment: As for the authentication, since other dlls are working, and I have not changed anything related to the user authentication, it does not seem to be the problem

Comment: @Ian I cannot test your answer because as much as I can see the dll code on source control, I am not allowed to recompile and change the dll

Comment: My problem was caused by not checking the property Allow IIS intrinsic properties on the COM+ components

Comment: @KellyGoedert Could you please add that as an answer, might help someone facing the same issue later.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was caused by not checking the property Allow IIS intrinsic properties on the COM+ components